# Удалить пустые значение

Tags: php

Добрый день. Тут кусок кода.

```
   $table = $html_product->find('#product_teh tbody',0);
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowa) {
        $td = $rowa->find('td');
        $theData[] = "Характеристики|".strip_tags($td[0])."|".strip_tags($td[1]);
    }
    $links_product['_TAT'] = $theData;
    $theData = implode($theData,PHP_EOL);


    $links_product['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = $theData;
```

Результат

```
                [0] => Характеристики||
                [1] => Характеристики||
                [2] => Характеристики||
                [3] => Характеристики|Тип|Котел газовый стандартный
                [4] => Характеристики|Количество контуров (назначение)|двухконтурный (отопление+горячее водоснабжение)
                [5] => Характеристики|Способ установки|навесной
                [6] => Характеристики|Диаметр дымохода (дымохода/воздуховода), мм|80/80
                [7] => Характеристики|Вид тяги|принудительная
                [8] => Характеристики|Тип камеры сгорания|закрытая (турбо)
                [9] => Характеристики|Мощность, кВт|25,8
                [10] => Характеристики|КПД, %|91,2
                [11] => Характеристики|Максимальный расход топлива|2,73 м3/ч
                [12] => Характеристики|Топливо|природный газ, сжиженный газ
                [13] => Характеристики|Теплоноситель|вода
                [14] => Характеристики|Необходимость подключения к электросети|есть
                [15] => Характеристики|Питание, В|220
                [16] => Характеристики|Габариты, мм (ШхВхГ)|400x770x315
                [17] => Характеристики|Вес, кг|30
                [18] => Характеристики|Дополнительно|Функция автоматического удаления воздуха из котла и системы отопления; функция самодиагностики и журнал аварий; возможность каскадного подключения до 8 котлов; стойкость к перепадам напряжения; встроенный конденсатосборник; работа при низкой уличной температуре (до -52°с); возможность снижения мощности на отопление и функция задержки включения; функция непрерывной электронной модуляции пламени горелки; 2 сверхточных датчика температуры ntc; фильтр механической очистки - в контуре отопления; возможность подключения clima manager, t-control и любых других устройств управления, встроенная погодозависимая автоматика; возможность управления солнечным коллектором
                [19] => Характеристики||
                [20] => Характеристики|Материал основного теплообменника|медь
                [21] => Характеристики|Регулируемый температурный диапазон в контуре отопления, град.C|35-82
                [22] => Характеристики|Площадь обогрева, кв.м|до 240
                [23] => Характеристики|Расширительный бак|да (6,5л)
                [24] => Характеристики||
                [25] => Характеристики|Бойлер, л|опция
                [26] => Характеристики|Материал вторичного теплообменника|нержавеющая сталь
                [27] => Характеристики|Производительность системы ГВС, л/мин|14,5 (при t=25°С)
                [28] => Характеристики|Регулируемый температурный диапазон в системе ГВС, град.C|36-60
                [29] => Характеристики||
                [30] => Характеристики|Тип розжига|автоматический розжиг
                [31] => Характеристики|Управление|электронный блок управления (невыносной)
                [32] => Характеристики|Циркуляционный насос|есть
                [33] => Характеристики|Режим "Лето"|есть
                [34] => Характеристики|Защита от замерзания|есть
                [35] => Характеристики|Защита от нарушения циркуляции теплоносителя|да (от блокировки циркуляционного насоса и 3-х ходового клапана)
```

Нужно удалить пустые значения **Характеристики||**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да ладно вам, это даже не серьезно :(

```
 $table = $html_product->find('#product_teh tbody',0);
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowa) {
        $td = $rowa->find('td');
        if (empty(strip_tags($td[0]))) continue; // пропускает шаг, если пустое значение
        $theData[] = "Характеристики|".strip_tags($td[0])."|".strip_tags($td[1]);
    }
    $links_product['_TAT'] = $theData;
    $theData = implode($theData,PHP_EOL);


    $links_product['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = $theData;
```

Comment: Я забыл !!! Прошу простить

Answer (score 0):

Пропускайте пустые значение с помощью `continue`:

```
$table = $html_product->find('#product_teh tbody',0);
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $rowa) {
        $td = $rowa->find('td');
        if(!$td[0] && !$td[1]) { continue; }
        $theData[] = "Характеристики|".strip_tags($td[0])."|".strip_tags($td[1]);
    }
    $links_product['_TAT'] = $theData;
    $theData = implode($theData,PHP_EOL);


    $links_product['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = $theData;
```

Comment: У Вас по логике ошибка получается, во-первых, если при парсинге попадется `<td><p></p></td>` характеристика запишется, во-вторых, если тип характеристики пустой, а сама характеристика есть (и наоборот) - она не будет иметь никакого смысла, но у вас так же эта характеристика добавится